# Concatenating multiple dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm performing some string operations to a given set of nested lists and I just want to create a single csv after concatenating these lists into a single dataframe .

I have a function like:

```
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'C:\\.........')
files = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i))]

for file in files:

    openfile = open(file,'r')
    new_line = []

    def separateState(l):
        for line in l:
            if any(x in line for x in ['NEW ENGLAND', 'MIDDLE ATLANTIC', 'E N CENTRAL', 'W N CENTRAL', 'SOUTH ATLANTIC', 'E S CENTRAL', 'W S CENTRAL', 'MOUNTAIN', 'PACIFIC']):     
                new_line.append(line.split())

    separateState(openfile)

    frames = list()

    def join_words(n):
        for listy in n:
            grouper = groupby(listy, key=str.isalpha)
            joins = [[' '.join(v)] if alpha_flag else list(v) for alpha_flag, v in grouper]
            res = list(chain.from_iterable(joins))
            df = pd.DataFrame(res)
            frames.append(df)
        df = pd.concat(frames)
        df['Date'] = os.path.split(file)[-1]
        df.to_csv('temp.csv', header = False)
        print(frames)

    join_words(new_line)
```

But this outputs a single dataframe per list because it's overriding the previous dataframe.

How can I manipulate this (it's a simple fix I think) so that I get a single dataframe and CSV file output from this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider re-factoring your code for organization and readability and it appears you need two `pd.concat` calls: at new line level and text file level.

Specifically, consider the following:

1. Place `def` calls outside of any loop with `return`. No need to re-define same function iteratively.
2. Use context manager `with` when reading files to avoid the need to close after processing.
3. Have loop call your functions to return outputs that are then concatenated at the end.

Adjusted Code:

```
def separateState(txt):
    new_line = []

    with open(txt, 'r') as l:
        for line in l:
            if any(x in line for x in ['NEW ENGLAND', 'MIDDLE ATLANTIC', 
                                       'E N CENTRAL', 'W N CENTRAL', 
                                       'SOUTH ATLANTIC', 'E S CENTRAL', 
                                       'W S CENTRAL', 'MOUNTAIN', 'PACIFIC']):     
                 new_line.append(line.split())

        return new_line

def join_words(n, txt):
    frames = list()

    for listy in n:
        grouper = groupby(listy, key=str.isalpha)
        joins = [[' '.join(v)] if alpha_flag else list(v) for alpha_flag, v in grouper]
        res = list(chain.from_iterable(joins))
        df = pd.DataFrame(res)
        df['Date'] = os.path.split(txt)[-1]
        frames.append(df)

    new_df = pd.concat(frames)
    return new_df


df_list = [] 
for file in files:          
    new_line = separateState(file)
    df = join_words(new_line, file)
    df_list.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
final_df.to_csv('temp.csv', header = False)
print(df_list)
```

Comment: This solution works. I needed the final_df second set of concatenation for it to parse. However, the final_df['Date'] needs to be placed right after the first definition of df = is made so that it can grab each file's name while appending each list. Your version at the end only takes the final file's name.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. You can pass *file* as  second argument in `join_words()` to be used for `df['Date']` assignment. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
frames = list()

def join_words(n):
    for listy in n:
        res = list(........does things to the lists)
        df = pd.DataFrame(res)
        frames.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(frames)
    df.to_csv('temp.csv', header = False)
```

Just accumulate each of the individual frames as you loop, then concatenate them all at the end.

Comment: The result of this code actually creates 1 CSV with only the very last dataframe in it. Is there a way to just push out a series of dataframes into one?

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct? The output of @Batman's code would be a single frame, with all the data in it.

Comment: I've updated my entire code so you can see what's happening. Basically taking all the path's .txt files into my script so I can parse them all as one big CSV along with attaching names of the files for references. @Batman the code you provided only creates 1 dataframe per iteration and the csv files is still only the very last parsed dataframe. I must be missing something because I feel my indentation is correct now.